# Combinations of subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics, interaction-combinators

**Problem.** Let $x = (x_1,...,x_N) \in K^{N}$, i.e., each element $x_j$ of $x$ can take $K$ discrete values. Let $x_{(i)}$, for $i \in 1,...,I,$ be a vector of overlapping subsets of $x$. For example, for $K = 2$, $N= 3$, and $I = 2$ we may have $x_{(1)} = (x_1,x_2)$ and $x_{(2)} = (x_2,x_3)$.

I am looking for an algorithm that constructs a set of elements $y \in K^{N}$
covering set of combinations for all $x_{(i)}$. To clarify, consider the simple example above. The possible $x$ are:
$$
\{000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111\}
$$
In this case, the choice for the above mentioning cover set is simple: $\{000,111,010,101\}$.

However, I was wondering if there is an algorithm that builds such a set automatically in the general case. It would be nice for the algorithm to be efficient for large $K, N$ and such that it builds the above-mentioned set with minimal size.

Comment: Subsets, or contiguous sequence?  Could you have $x_{(1)}=(x_1,x_7)$?

Comment: What does "covering set of combinations for all $x_{(i)}$" mean?  That isn't even grammatical.  Please specify the problem clearly in general form.  An example is not a substitute for a clear specification of the problem.

Comment: @D.W. subsets, they can be non-contiguous

Comment: Covering set of combinations means that all the local combinations of $x_{(i)}$ are in the covering sets

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it is clear to someone who encounters this for the first time.

Comment: Your response just raises more questions for me.  You haven't defined what you mean by "local combinations".  I don't know what you mean by "covering sets" - the previous sentences says "constructs a set", singular.  I suggest you try formulating the problem statement in mathematics, specify the inputs and outputs for the algorithm, and the mathematical conditions under which the output is correct.